# How to validate fields in sub component when we try to change the Tab with route?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material, angular-ui-router

need your help, I researched but have not found any relevant solution.

I have one shared component which is having this code, which I'm using for tab navigation through routes.

```
  <a mat-tab-link #tablink *ngFor="let link of navLinks; let i = index" [routerLink]="link.link" routerLinkActive
    #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive" [ngClass]="{'invalid': link.inValid}">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
<div class="zin-tab-body content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="controls" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="32px" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">
  <div fxFlex="90"></div>
  <button [disabled]="!hasPrev" mat-raised-button color="primary" id="prev-btn" (click)="prev()" matTooltip="previous">
    Prev
  </button>
  <button [disabled]="!hasNext" mat-raised-button color="primary" id="next-btn" (click)="next()" matTooltip="Next">
    Next
  </button>
</div>
```

For each route having different components,

On next click from this component it changes root.

```
next() {
    if (this.activeLinkIndex !== (this.navLinks.length -1)) {
      const locationConfig = this.navLinks.find(d => d.index === (this.activeLinkIndex + 1))
      this.router.navigate([`${locationConfig.link}`], { relativeTo: this.route})   
    }
  }
```

In this case, is it possible to validate that sub component on clicking next before it changes the route? And restrict to changing route if invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the life-cycle of a component, you cannot directly validate your sub-component, before you click it on next aka before your parent-component has been loaded, because a component loads after the URL has matched (or page has been called by routing).

What you could do is adding children in your routing or rename your URL with /:type/:step as a principal route.

And if an URL doesn't exist, you can redirect to a custom error page.
Should this solve your issue?

Example:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: Page1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'page2/:id',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: Page2Component
  },
  {
    path: 'edit-me',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: EditMeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [{
        path: ':id/:name',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: UserComponent
      } // localhost:4200/users/anyID
    ]
  }, // localhost:4200/users
  {
    path: 'edit-user/:id',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: EditUserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'add-user',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: AddUserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'statistics',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: StatisticComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: OrdersComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'logout',
    component: LogoutComponent
  },
  // Here is how you can redirect to a custom Error Page
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: ErrorPageComponent,
    data: {
      message: ''
    }
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/not-found'
  }
];
```

What you could also do, is redirect in the parent component, if a ViewChild-Component is undefined.

Add your child component in your parent component with viewchild:
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild